# Detailed, offline web mapping for the US and United Kingdom markets

Tags: offline, maps

I am a developer tasked with picking a mapping solution to create choropleth maps for the US and UK markets and I am finding it extremely difficult to find a product that can meet all my requirements. I am looking for a mapping solution that can:

- Produce interactive maps for a web based application
- Map down to the US Zip code level
- Map down to the UK Postcode level
- Create [choropleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) maps
- Have a good API for working with SQL Server and C#
- Reasonable pricing (if not open source).
- Run inside a firewall (no calling out to 3rd party services) **

** This could be the requirement I drop if no software exists otherwise.

Hopefully such a product exists and I am not searching in vain.